# Detecting a new page in Prawn

Tags: ruby, prawn

Scanning the documentation for Prawn, there are some helpful functions for starting new pages and adding page numbering, but what if you want to have some sensitivity to what you do in a document based on the page number?  Does anyone know of a method that gets the current page number?  If not, what would you recommend to reliably detect what page you are on?

Answer (score 4):

Prawn provides a method to access the page count, even though it's not in the manual it is used in the *number_pages* helper, if it's helpful there is also another method called *go_to_page(n)* to access a specific page, but I haven't test it.

```
page_count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the (current) page number with the method:

```
PrawnView#page_number
# or Prawn::Document#page_number
```

([see Prawn::Document](https://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html))

So in real life:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(...)
# ... some stuff to add content
3.times { pdf.start_new_page }
pdf.page_number
# => current page number
```